# How to test Ember error substate, with Ember CLI test runner?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've set up an error substate route/controller/template according to http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/. Manually browsing my app, I can trigger error conditions and get directed to the substate. Confirmed with Ember Inspector.

I'd like to automatically test the substate. However, Ember CLI's test runner fails any test when a route's `model` hook rejects. In other words, the test fails before I can navigate to the error substate.

How can I automatically test my error substate?

Ember: 2.2.0

Ember CLI: 1.13.13

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be easy to do this in a clean manner.

In its internal tests, Ember uses `bootApplication` to the route which errors (see [github](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember/tests/routing/substates_test.js#L374L416)) and is able to directly catch the error. Unfortunately if you try and do any form of `try/catch` or `then/catch` around a call to `visit` in your tests you will find it fails.

When you `visit` a link which results in an error substate from your acceptance test then Ember's `defaultActionHandlers.error` gets fired. By design it is not meant to be overridable. It calls `logError` which calls `Ember.default.Logger.error`.

So to test this substate we need to temporarily overwrite that method. We can also peek inside the ember container to access the `currentRouteName` like so (using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) for the spying):

```
test('when there is an API error an error message is shown', function(assert) {

  const emberLoggerError = Ember.Logger.error;
  Ember.Logger.error = sinon.spy();

  visit('/users/');

  andThen(() => {
    // This could be nicer and less private with `getOwner`
    let { currentRouteName } = this.application.__container__.lookup('router:main');
    assert.equal(currentRouteName, 'users.index_error', 'The current route name is correct');
    assert.equal(Ember.Logger.error.callCount, 1, 'The error logger was called');

    // Restore the Ember.Logger
    Ember.Logger.error = emberLoggerError;
  });
});
```

Things can get even more complicated though. If your `visit` happens inside a Promise (it did in our case because we were using [ember-page-object](https://github.com/linstula/ember-page-object) for our tests) then you have more to deal with...

In a separate loop `onerrorDefault` of `RSVP` is triggered which calls `Test.adapter.exception` AND `Ember.default.Logger.error` (again!) - passing the stack. So in this case you need to stub and spy on `Test.adapter.exception` **and** expect `Ember.default.Logger.error` to have been called twice!

Comment: This put me on the right path. Perhaps Ember 2.3.0 has smoothed this over. To make my test not fail, all I need to do is stub `Ember.Test.adapter.exception`. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/john-kurkowski/da3abb95329f14f19c19/6936cab4cb0a8cb0168137c5a6426cfc0a15aacb).